# Trying to display PDF returned by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, pdf, jsreport

I'm trying to get a PDF report created by jsreport and display it in a new window/tab.

The ajax response contains data, which looks like PDF content:

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<<
/Title ...
```

When I try to display the data with

```
window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,' + data);
```

a new, empty tab opens - nothing is displayed.

When I try:

```
window.open('data:application/pdf,' + data);
```

a new tab with PDF-plugin opens, telling that the content is not correct.
The URL-address is displayed as:

```
data:application/pdf,%PDF-1.410obj<</Title(%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD)/Creator(%EF%
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You get into various cross browser issues with ajax and pdf from my experience. Assuming you get pdf by posting to jsreport server it is more easier and more stable to use just simple http form post into a new tab for this.

```
<form method='POST' target='_blank' action='http://<jsreport>/api/report' id='jsrForm'>
        <input hidden='true' type='text'name='template[shortid]' value="xykdJcxR5"/>       
        <input hidden='true' type='text'name='data[foo]' value="1"/>
</form>
```

Submitting this form should open a new tab with report

```
document.getElementById("jsrForm").submit();
```

You can also check this [documentation](http://jsreport.net/learn/embedding) for jsreport browser support and rendering.